# Regex to catch specific anchor formula

Tags: c#, regex

I have an html file, that file contains html tags I want to select all anchors that have specific formula that formula like the following

```
<a href="AnyTextHereFollowingByThatChar/" target="_blank">
```

I write regex like that following

```
\<a\s*href\=\"(.*?)"\s*target\="_blank"
```

but this regex select the first anchor that it match until find keyword target on any other anchor and then stop after selecting all characters in between.

> Appreciate any help to catch those anchors `<a href="AnyTextHereFollowingByThatChar/" target="_blank">`

Comment: Regex for html is fought with problems, if this is nested in a larger html document id consider using http://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: what is this html-agility-pack.net @TheGeneral

Comment: Its a dedicated *Jedi* html parsing library, and will make short work of your html dilemmas. Well... after an abrupt learning curve and several more SO questions

Comment: Seconded on not attempting to do this with a direct regex. [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) will let you extract object representations of the elements and attributes you're looking for, that can be more safely queried in the manner you're attempting.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions can have [unfortunate effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392) on one's mental state: don't do it.

Comment: *. Even Jon Skeet or Chuck Norris cannot parse HTML using regular expressions*

Comment: With html/xml file, why don't you use XML Validator - XSD (XML Schema) instead of regex?

Comment: Thank you all for your time I reach to the correct regex :)
This is the regex that I need
\<a\s*href\="(?<value>[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^/])*\/"\s*target\="_blank">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I reached to the regex that I need

```
\<a\s*href\="(?<value>[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^/])*\/"\s*target\="_blank">
```

this regex will select only the anchor that I need as in the question above